# ListView ordered

Tags: android, listview

I have created a "BaseAdapter" for a "ListView". I want to order the elements in the list, so the constructor of my "BaseAdapter" receive an ordered array of the elements. But I don't know why, the elements are not ordered properly.

```
public class NotificacionesAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  private NotificacionInfo[] notificaciones = null;

  static class ViewHolder
  {
   TextView titulo;
   TextView mensaje;
   TextView fecha;
  }

  public static class NotificacionInfo implements Comparable<NotificacionInfo>
  {
    private String titulo;
    private String mensaje;
    private Date fecha; 

    public NotificacionInfo()
    {       
    }

    public String getTitulo()
    {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo)
    {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getMensaje()
    {
        return mensaje;
    }

    public void setMensaje(String mensaje)
    {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }

    public Date getFecha()
    {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha)
    {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(NotificacionInfo another)
    {
        return another.getFecha().compareTo(this.fecha);            
    }           
  }

  public NotificacionesAdapter(Context context, NotificacionInfo[] notificaciones)
  {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);       
    this.notificaciones = notificaciones;

    Arrays.sort(this.notificaciones);

    System.out.println ();
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount()
  {
    return this.notificaciones.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int arg0)
  {
    return notificaciones[arg0];
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) 
  {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null)
    { 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.t_notificacion, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.titulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        holder.mensaje = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mensaje);
        holder.fecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fecha); 

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {           
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.titulo.setText(notificaciones[position].getTitulo());
    holder.mensaje.setText(notificaciones[position].getMensaje());
    holder.fecha.setText(DateUtil.formatDate(notificaciones[position].getFecha(), "HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy"));

    return convertView;
  }

  public void setNotificaciones (NotificacionInfo[] notificaciones)
  {
    Arrays.sort(this.notificaciones);
    this.notificaciones = notificaciones;
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this happen when you try to use setNotifications() method or from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is complex. Make it easy. In your constructor copy the array, then sort it using a `java.util.Comparator;` with a condition. you will find many samples of Comparator exaple in this site.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. But in the constructor, instead of using java.util.Comparator, I'm using Arrays.sort method.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've done as you told me and it works. Although I don't undestand why it doesn't work using java.util.Comparator.

Comment: actually I am also surprised, because your code is probably correct. The problem may occur as per the Ans. provided by **@Tomislav**. Ok... you problem is solved :) From my experience using java.util.Comparator is a better approach, & I always use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Arrays.sort(this.notificaciones);
 this.notificaciones = notificaciones;
```

why do you first sort your objects, and the override them with unsorted list?